# Замена слова в тексте на ссылку?

Tags: php

Сделал скрипт, вышло так:

```
$data='test,test 1,test 2,test 3';//чтение строки в переменную
$txt=explode(',', $data);
foreach ($txt as $value)
{
$text.="<a href=\"search.php?d=$value\">$value</a>, ";
}
echo "$text\n";
```

выводит так:

```
a href="search.php?d=test">test</a>, a href="search.php?d=test 1">test 1</a>, a href="search.php?d=test 2">test 2</a>, a href="search.php?d=test 3">test 3</a>,
```

как сделать чтобы в href выходило так:

```
a href="search.php?d=test-1">test 1</a>, a href="search.php?d=test-2">test 2</a>,
```

- То есть пробелы нужно заменить на -
- и как убрать запятую в конце?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data='test,test 1,test 2,test 3';//чтение строки в переменную
$txt=explode(',', $data);
foreach ($txt as $value)
{
    $d = str_replace(' ', '-', $value);
    $text[]="<a href=\"search.php?d=$d\">$value</a>";
}
echo implode(',', $text);
```

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ!!!

Comment: Дублируете вопросы @jikol :) Я бы вам порекоммендовал бы пропустить $d через urlencode() перед добавлением в ссылку, типа того, как я ответил вам тут http://hashcode.ru/questions/295536/php-замена-слова-в-тексте-на-ссылку

Comment: @jikol, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом). А то у вас 0% принятых, неужели никто вам не ответил правильно? :))

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понял вопрос, но через html можно сделать ссылку вот таким образом

```
<?php 
$data='test,test 1,test 2,test 3';//чтение строки в переменную
$txt=explode(',', $data);
foreach ($txt as $value)
{
    $d = str_replace(' ', '-', $value);
 ?>

<a href="search.php?d=$d">Текст</a>

<?php 
}
echo implode(',', $text);
 ?>
```